Azure AD B2C, Auto-linking on signup working for with Google but not for Apple
Azure B2c provides a lot of samples for custom policies, this case the one that I am trying to implement is the following:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/auto-account-linking
This is my version of the AccountLinkExtensions.xml:
https://pastebin.com/WGerhQkZ
<SubJourney Id="HandleLinkLocalToSocial" Type="Transfer">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <!-- if we got an local account email now and is social auth not associated with this email, 
    present page to sign in with local or any other socials as account exists with this email -->
    <!-- Sample: Link the new social account. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>containsIssuerAlready</Value>
          <Value>True</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="UpdateUserIdentities" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UpdateUserIdentitiesToLocalUser" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
</SubJourney>

In my version I removed the steps of "HandleLinkLocalToSocial" subjourney from 1 to 7.
For the sake of simplicity, ignore the microsoft and twitter implementation (twitter for now does not work).
Current Behavior:
---Google---

SSO with google account will merge with existing local account if the email is the same
If local account doesn't exist, create a local account and link it to the google account, using the email address as a "primary key".

---Apple---
*SSO with Apple account, creates a new local account linked to apple account regardless if there is already a local account. This means the same local account will exist linked to apple and standalone if the local account already existed.
Expected Behavior:

When doing SSO with a IDP, it will merge with the existing local account.
If local account does not exist, create a local account and link it to the idp (using email address as "primary key").

Basically I am confused on why with my current implementation, the Apple SSO behaves differently from the Google SSO.
Update:
I noticed the received token does not have the intended email. It should be something like "something@gmail.com", but is 
I'm thinking the reason the current behavior is what it is, is due to the email in the token being the different from the one I expect.
Note that the email used to login is not what's in the image of the token's attribute.

Could you include more details like Portal images to make it more clear?

@Sridevi The portal is a simple sign up, like the sample code. A signin/signup page with, username and password input, signIn/singup buttons and 2 other buttons, one that redirects to google to login and the other to apple (I can't show the portal page, due to NDA).

The user is probably using Hide My Email function with apple login, therefore you'll not be able to match on email in this scenario. You would need to consider another way of account linking, such as eKYC

@bolt-io Reading a bit about it, I just realized you are right...Kinda leaves me at a loss to how even find a way around this.

One option: if no match, prompt them to provide more info about them/their account, then use that to locate and match.
